# Transparent background in Flex Air For Android?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, transparent, air-android

Can a Flex Air Android app have transparent background, like the Android Theme.Transluscent? I've tried adding:

```
    <systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
    <transparent>true</transparent>
```

to the -app file but that just makes the background white. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering own question: It's not possible. The transparent theme has to be set in the main activity's theme tag in the android manifest. But the theme tag in the android manifest can not be overridden via the Flex mobile android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use fill:

```
      <fill>  
           <SolidColor color="#000000" alpha="0"/>  
      </fill>
```

Not sure which file that code is in.

Also, this may be useful to read through: http://oreilly.com/flex/excerpts/flex-4-cookbook/graphics.html

Comment: I tried that in an Application Skin but it just made the background all black, not transparent.

Comment: Try changing the alpha a bit, maybe. anywhere from `alpha="0"` `alpha="1"` I think. So `alpha="0.5"` would be valid too. Play around. Or even try `backgroundAlpha="0"` Sorry for all the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Gunnar idea, by decompiling the apk with apk-tools, changing the activity theme and rebuilding it. Doesn't work. At least by only doing this. I'll try other combinations of things and if I succeed, I'll post here.